# Unable to update the schema with cassandra 0.8.2

Tags: schema, cassandra, database-indexes

I have single node cassandra installion with 0.8.2 . I have created some column families with cassandra-cli like

```
create column family demo;
```

Now i have to use secondary indexes over this column family.For that i need to upgrade the schema.When i try to upgrade this with cassandra-cli like

```
update column family demo with comparator=BytesType and column_metadata=[{column_name: col1, validation_class: UTF8Type, index_type: KEYS}];
```

i get the following error message

> org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.MarshalException: cannot parse 'col1'

I have tried using the bytes('col1') , assume keyword ,ascii and utf8 none of them works.

> as hex bytes

While the same thing works perfectly fine with cassandra 0.8.4

Comment: did you try with a hex value, e.g. "column_name: 636f6c31", since the comparator is BytesType, I believe it is expecting bytes. Not sure why the change from versions...

Comment: I thought the same and tried it with the hex value ,it works but when i try to get the values using where col1='some value' it returns zero rows.

Comment: What does your column family look like when you do cassandra-cli 'describe demo'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question.  It's a bug in 0.8.2 and you should upgrade.  (To the latest 0.8 release, which is 0.8.7 at this time.)

Comment: even 0.8.7 do not support this

Comment: i can update the same schema by providing the hexbytes of the column we have to index.